# GeoServer cascaded WMS - Styles not working

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms

I'm cascading (remote) WMS with GeoServer. I use Leaflet to display the layer "granser" that shows property boundaries in Sweden. The governmental version of this site can be found here: https://kso.etjanster.lantmateriet.se/?lang=en# (zoom in and the yellow boundaries will appear). The yellow styling is called "morkbakgrund" and is used for dark backgrounds, like the orthophoto.

According to the technical document for the WMS, two styles exist: "ljusbakgrund" and "morkbakgrund" for the layer "granser". https://www.lantmateriet.se/globalassets/kartor-och-geografisk-information/geodatatjanster/tb_fastighetsindelningvisning_v1.2.pdf (unfortunately in Swedish)

**Question:**

I am able to show the layer on my site as long as I'm not using any `styles:` parameter. Then it's displaying with the default style ("ljusbakgrund"). However, when I add `styles: 'morkbakgrund'` nothing shows. This is the code:

```
var wmsLayer = new L.TileLayer.WMS('https://my_url/wms/', {
    layers: 'granser',
    styles: 'morkbakgrund',
    format:'image/png',
    transparent:true
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Instead of returning PNG, I'm getting vnd.ogc.se_xml saying:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "https://my_url/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException code="StyleNotDefined">
      No such style: morkbakgrund
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

If I open the WMS-layer in QGIS, I am able to select the styled layer "morkbakgrund" and display it on the map - so it does exist.

Is there anything at my side I'm doing wrong, or could it be a setting at the service providers side that is causing this trouble? Can I ask them to make any specific changes so that it works? They say they use Mapstore themselves, instead of GeoServer, but that shouldn't be a problem, right?

------ UPDATE ------

As pointed out in one of the comments I am in fact connecting to the host URL in QGIS and not my Geoserver URL. That is probably why it works in QGIS. In contact with the host of the WMS layer, they suggest to directly connect to their URL instead of via my Geoserver. The WMS however require basic authorization with username and password.

I used to add the credentials in Geoserver, but now when I shall connect without Geoserver, how can I add them without the obvious security problems of adding them in the url (which anyway don't work)?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know how you configured your cascading WMS (https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html#cascaded-wms-settings) did you configure the remote styles?

Comment: Can you clarify in the question, when you open the WMS service in QGIS and can see the `granser` layer with two styles, the service URL is your GeoServer service, and not the original service.

Comment: When you say that nothing shows, do you mean an error, or a blank image?

Comment: @nmtoken, yes you where right about the URL. I was in fact using the service URL in QGIS. Please see the updated question. Perhaps you have any suggestion on how to solve my next issue?