# GeoServer External WMS - Style parameter not working

Tags: geoserver, wms, geoserver-styling, cascading

I'm cascading (remote) WMS with GeoServer.

I get an error message: "unable to fetch remote styles" and the layer is displayed in the default remote style.

[image]

According to [The documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html) "remote styles can be passed in a GetMap request just like local styles."

[image]

The problem is when I'm trying to pass a remote style by adding a value to the parameter STYLES= , nothing happens and the layer is still displayed in the default style.

I've found a similar question here: [GeoServer cascaded WMS - Styles not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354432/geoserver-cascaded-wms-styles-not-working)

Comment: Have you tried to follow the documentation https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: Remote styles can be referenced through the `Styles` parameter, but the Server still needs to know the style, either passed through an `SLD` parameter by reference to a public SLD file or directly using the `SLD_BODY` parameter.